# Does anyone know of a program like Winplot?

Tags: upload, hyperlink

Someone could tell me if there is any other program that shows graphs of functions online? is because I'm using a computer where I can not do downloads, and needed an online version. 
Very Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how Winplot works but have you tried [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)?

Also there is:

1. [Fooplot](http://www.fooplot.com/)
2. [Rechneronline](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/)
3. [Plotgraphs.com](http://www.plotgraphs.com/)

Comment: Any example of function you want to get plotted @user73276 ?